# Does acccessing nested FK relation's field value downgrade performance?

Tags: django, django-views

I have various models which are interconnected through Foreign key relations, does doing this make any performance downside. I want to know how does django perform this internally.

```
PriceSheet.objects.select_related('query').filter(
    id=pricesheet_id
).values(
    'query__campaign_name', 'query_id', 'query__campaign_status',
    'query__lead_id', 'query__lead__legal_name', 'query__lead__brand_name' # nested
    'query__lead__working_capital', 'query__lead__payment_terms'
)  # 7
```

Comment: depends on your data and database. Django will create sql joins to get the values. Set environment variable `DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` to [see all your queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/#examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the query by printing:

```
print(queryset.query)
```

In that case Django will print the query that it will make. In this case, the query will look like:

```
SELECT query.campaign_name, price_sheet.id, query.campaign_status,
       query.lead_id, lead.legal_name, lead.brand_name,
       lead.working_capital, lead.payment_terms
FROM price_sheet
LEFT OUTER JOIN query ON query.id = price_sheet.query_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead ON lead.id = query.lead_id
WHERE price_sheet.id = pricesheet_id
```

Django will thus make `JOIN`s on the models referenced by the `query` and by the `lead` of the `query`. Using [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to force a `JOIN` is *not* necessary in this case.

Usually it is better *not* to work with [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) when you want to convert data to a JSON blob, since it erodes the logical layer that the model(s) provide. For a field with choices for example, you can no longer (easily) access the display name, etc.